# How to override values/file in framework in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode9, ios-frameworks

I have developed the application in ios. It is working fine. I have converted it as a framework(library) so that My codebase remain same.

I have multiple clients for this app. So I need to change the following things

1. Colors (As it will change the background colors, text colors etc)
2. Strings (Like headings and labels in some views)
3. Some files like Images etc

**What I want:**

As I am android developer, So in that I can create another color file in my client app with same color name, that replaces the color value in Library. and this it just require only one file to be replace and it automatically overrides in library. Same was the case with the String.xml and image files

Looking for something like that as I have described above.

**What I searched and found so far:**

> After searching alot I have found that I need to make outlets public and then I can give them color by accessing them. But What If I have a 1000 of views and 1000s of outlets to make to use this technique, Isnt it better to use it as same way as in android I described above.

**Confusions:**

- Is there anyway in IOS to declare color in a file and to use them in IB and code as well. Well I read about Color.xcassets but that is for ios 11 I think
- How to make strings file and to use them in IB and in code. Like strings.xml file in android?

So I short, I want to updated colors,Strings and file per client wise and I do not know how to do it and what is a best way of doing this??

Please help and thanks in advance. Please share your views.

Comment: Why can't you do it the same way as before? For example, set up your framework in such a way that the client can hand you a configuration file — a _.plist_ or other XML file in a predetermined format — and you read that and respond accordingly. After all, that is how localization works — when _all the strings in the interface_ are replaced by strings in a different language. It's just a file full of strings that are substituted at runtime.

Comment: For that I do not know how the replace will work . I even do not know how to read colors or strings in the p.list into the IB

Comment: "I even do not know how to read colors or strings in the p.list into the IB" You can't read them "into the IB". That's not what "the IB" is. You can't change a nib file when the app is running. You would make the changes _in code_.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your framework to read from predefined files in *.plist* file. this will require only changing the files content in the client application.

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please share me any code ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to handle colors and theme using [SkinKit](https://github.com/nubbel/SkinKit). This is too old code. You just reuse idea or create custom themes configuration file(plist,JSON),Strings and images as .bundle read all color and customization from that bundle. So easy to change Colors, Strings and Images assert for various clients.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misconception about what IB is — in particular, what a nib is, and what it means to edit a nib, which is what Interface Builder does. A nib is a file expressing potential instances, typically views. You edit it on your computer using Xcode (IB). When your app runs, the nib is *loaded* and the views are actually *instantiated*. That is the *only* thing you can do with a nib when the app runs. You cannot *modify* the nib in some way when the app runs; all you can do is load the nib and get the instances.

So, if you want to change all the titles of buttons or all the colors of views when your app runs in accordance with some configuration file, you can do that, but that has nothing to do with nibs or IB. You would just load the nib as usual to get the views, and then change them all, one by one, in code. You could use *tags* or some other identification mechanism to help you *find* each view, but that would be entirely up to you to work out.

Comment: Great explanation but How it can be done using Workspace, as I want my code base to be same, and with your logic , it means that I have to change color for each view via code, so perhaps I am better to use code for each client separately ?